# knitr chunk math notation

Tags: r, math, knitr, lyx

I am unable to render maths notation inside a knitr chunk in Lyx although it renders fine using \Sexpr or in an ERT box while using Lyx 2.0.5 and knitr 1.1

The following code was adapted from the manual:

```
<<cars-demo,dev='svg',fig.width=4,fig.height=2.8,out.width='.45\\textwidth',message=TRUE,cache=TRUE>>=
fit=lm(dist~speed,data=cars) # linear regression
par(mar=c(4, 4, 1, .1), mgp=c(2,1,0))
with(cars,plot(speed,dist,panel.last=abline(fit)))
text(10,100,'$\alpha_{1}$+$\beta^{2}$')
```

The plot is fine but the text notation appears exactly as: $\alpha_{1}$+$\beta^{2}$

I cannot run tikz for some reason so the original dev = tikz had to be converted to svg.

Thanks in advance. Great combination Lyx and knitr.

Comment: I don't think latex math works in plots using any device other than tikz.

Comment: Yes, `tikz` is the only choice if you want LaTeX math in plots.

Comment: omg its yihui the god of knitr

Comment: Inkscape can process svg to latex http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2099/how-to-include-svg-diagrams-in-latex -- you could post process the graphics like this.

Comment: Thanks but the problem continues. I have already put a tikz figure in the same document and it renders fine but the moment I replace dev='svg' with dev='tikz' I get the following error message in a grey box with no error message from lyx. Lyx merely indicates a warning to have a larger side margin.

Comment: sorry the above went off before I could finish:An error occurred while running:
Rscript --verbose --no-save --no-restore
"/usr/local/share/lyx/scripts/lyxknitr.R"
"/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.T27306/lyx_tmpbuf4/""01KnitrManual.Rnw"
"/tmp/lyx_tmpdir.T27306/lyx_tmpbuf4/""01KnitrManual.tex" ISO-8859-15
"/home/samar/Desktop/NewProjectsDone/coursera/DataAnalysis/LearningR/"